# Question about the BCP cryptosystem

Tags: multiparty-computation

Is it possible to have a multiparty untrusted generation of the public parameters for the BCP cryptosystem (https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2003/01_Session01/03_106/28940037.pdf), so that a minimum threshold of parties be needed to use the master key?